# Emulate a file pointer C++?

Tags: c++, file, pointers, bitmap

I am trying to load a bitmap from an archive. The bitmap class I have takes a character pointer to a filename and then loads it if it is in the same directory. The bitmap loading class is well tested and I don't want to mess with it too much. Problem is it uses a file pointer to load and do all of its file manipulation. Is there any way to emulate a file pointer and actually have it read from a chunk in memory instead?

Sorry if this is a bizarre question.

Comment: Do you mean a file pointer as in `FILE *`, or...?

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen Yes. A FILE *

Comment: Just to clarify, by "a chunk of memory", do you mean that you have a `char *` that points to some buffer somewhere?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth Yes. Sorry. I forget to specify things but I am learning :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [John Ratcliff's File Interface](http://codesuppository.blogspot.com/2007/01/fileinterface-useful-code-snippet.html) replacement for standard file I/O.  It supports the feature you need.

You'll still need to refactor the bitmap loading code to use the new interface.  However, this interface supports loading from file on disk, or memory chunk in memory (as well as writing to file on disk, or to expandable memory chunks).

Answer (score 5):

Refactor it and create functions that takes the exact same parameters as before : If you used fopen, fread and fseek that read from disk, create mopen, mread and mseek that read file from memory. You'll only have to fix the name of the functions.

It should be easy without risk and code won't look like an dirty hack in the end.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use a pipe. A pipe is a piece of memory where you can read and write using file primitives. Which is basically what you want

(Assuming POSIX Operating system)

create a pipe:

```
int p[2]; 
pipe(p);
```

use fdopen() to turn the pipe file descriptor into a `FILE*`

```
FILE *emulated_file = fdopen(p[0], "r");
```

then write whatever you want to the write end of the pipe :

```
write(p[1], 17 ,"whatevereyouwant");
```

Now :

```
buf[32];
fread(&buf,1,32, emulated_file); 
cout<<buf<<endl;
```

willl output "whateveryouwant".

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think Windows 7 supports POSIX. Thanks anyway!